# Using shift function along with max function Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am attempting to create a technical indicator ('Supertrend') using Pandas. The formula for this column is recursive.
(For people familiar with Pinescript, this column will replicate the result of [this Pinescript function](https://gist.github.com/marketcalls/7752fc46a3095abcd3bf)):

```
df['st_trendup'] = np.select(df['Close'].shift() > df['st_trendup'].shift(),df[['st_up','st_trendup'.shift()]].max(axis=1),df['st_up'])
```

The problem occurs in the `true` part of the `np.select()`because I cannot call `.shift()` on a string.

- Normally, I would make a new column that uses `.shift()` beforehand but since this is recursive, I have to do it all in one line.
- If possible I'd like to avoid using loops for speed; prefer solutions using native pandas or numpy functions.

#### What I am looking for

A way to find `max` function that can accomodate a `.shift()` call

Columns that are used:

```
def tr(high,low,close1):
    return max(high - low, abs(high - close1), abs(low - close1))
df['st_closeprev'] = df['Close'].shift()
df['st_hl2'] = (df['High']+df['Low'])/2
df['st_tr'] = df.apply(lambda row: tr(row['High'],row['Low'],row['st_closeprev']),axis=1)
df['st_atr'] = df['st_tr'].ewm(alpha = 1/pd,adjust=False,min_periods=pd).mean()
df['st_up'] = df['st_hl2'] - factor * df['st_atr']
df['st_dn'] = df['st_hl2'] + factor * df['st_atr']
df['st_trendup'] = np.select(df['Close'].shift() > df['st_trendup'].shift(),df[['st_up','st_trendup'.shift()]].max(axis=1),df['st_up'])
```

Sample data obtained by the df.to_dict

```
    {'Date': {0: Timestamp('2021-01-01 09:15:00'),
  1: Timestamp('2021-01-01 09:30:00'),
  2: Timestamp('2021-01-01 09:45:00'),
  3: Timestamp('2021-01-01 10:00:00'),
  4: Timestamp('2021-01-01 10:15:00'),
  5: Timestamp('2021-01-01 10:30:00'),
  6: Timestamp('2021-01-01 10:45:00'),
  7: Timestamp('2021-01-01 11:00:00'),
  8: Timestamp('2021-01-01 11:15:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2021-01-01 11:30:00'),
  10: Timestamp('2021-01-01 11:45:00'),
  11: Timestamp('2021-01-01 12:00:00'),
  12: Timestamp('2021-01-01 12:15:00'),
  13: Timestamp('2021-01-01 12:30:00'),
  14: Timestamp('2021-01-01 12:45:00'),
  15: Timestamp('2021-01-01 13:00:00'),
  16: Timestamp('2021-01-01 13:15:00'),
  17: Timestamp('2021-01-01 13:30:00'),
  18: Timestamp('2021-01-01 13:45:00'),
  19: Timestamp('2021-01-01 14:00:00'),
  20: Timestamp('2021-01-01 14:15:00'),
  21: Timestamp('2021-01-01 14:30:00'),
  22: Timestamp('2021-01-01 14:45:00'),
  23: Timestamp('2021-01-01 15:00:00'),
  24: Timestamp('2021-01-01 15:15:00'),
  25: Timestamp('2021-01-04 09:15:00')},
 'Open': {0: 31250.0,
  1: 31376.0,
  2: 31405.0,
  3: 31389.4,
  4: 31377.5,
  5: 31347.8,
  6: 31310.8,
  7: 31343.4,
  8: 31349.5,
  9: 31349.9,
  10: 31325.1,
  11: 31310.9,
  12: 31329.0,
  13: 31376.0,
  14: 31375.5,
  15: 31357.4,
  16: 31325.0,
  17: 31341.1,
  18: 31300.0,
  19: 31324.5,
  20: 31353.3,
  21: 31350.0,
  22: 31346.9,
  23: 31330.0,
  24: 31314.3,
  25: 31450.2},
 'High': {0: 31407.0,
  1: 31425.0,
  2: 31411.95,
  3: 31389.45,
  4: 31382.0,
  5: 31350.0,
  6: 31354.6,
  7: 31359.0,
  8: 31370.0,
  9: 31364.7,
  10: 31350.0,
  11: 31337.9,
  12: 31378.9,
  13: 31419.5,
  14: 31377.75,
  15: 31360.0,
  16: 31367.15,
  17: 31345.2,
  18: 31340.0,
  19: 31367.0,
  20: 31375.0,
  21: 31370.0,
  22: 31350.0,
  23: 31334.6,
  24: 31329.6,
  25: 31599.0},
 'Low': {0: 31250.0,
  1: 31367.95,
  2: 31352.5,
  3: 31331.65,
  4: 31301.4,
  5: 31303.05,
  6: 31310.0,
  7: 31325.05,
  8: 31335.35,
  9: 31315.35,
  10: 31281.9,
  11: 31292.0,
  12: 31316.25,
  13: 31352.05,
  14: 31335.0,
  15: 31322.0,
  16: 31318.25,
  17: 31261.55,
  18: 31283.3,
  19: 31324.5,
  20: 31322.0,
  21: 31332.15,
  22: 31324.1,
  23: 31300.15,
  24: 31280.0,
  25: 31430.0},
 'Close': {0: 31375.0,
  1: 31398.3,
  2: 31386.0,
  3: 31377.0,
  4: 31342.3,
  5: 31311.7,
  6: 31345.0,
  7: 31349.0,
  8: 31344.2,
  9: 31327.6,
  10: 31311.3,
  11: 31325.6,
  12: 31373.0,
  13: 31375.0,
  14: 31357.4,
  15: 31326.0,
  16: 31345.9,
  17: 31300.6,
  18: 31324.4,
  19: 31353.8,
  20: 31345.6,
  21: 31341.6,
  22: 31332.5,
  23: 31311.0,
  24: 31285.0,
  25: 31558.4},
 'Volume': {0: 259952,
  1: 163775,
  2: 105900,
  3: 99725,
  4: 115175,
  5: 78625,
  6: 67675,
  7: 46575,
  8: 53350,
  9: 54175,
  10: 96975,
  11: 80925,
  12: 79475,
  13: 147775,
  14: 38900,
  15: 64925,
  16: 52425,
  17: 142175,
  18: 81800,
  19: 74950,
  20: 68550,
  21: 40350,
  22: 47150,
  23: 119200,
  24: 222875,
  25: 524625}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
df[['st_up','st_trendup'.shift()]].max(axis=1)
```

to:

```
df[['st_up','st_trendup']].assign(st_trendup = df['st_trendup'].shift()).max(axis=1)
```

Comment: I'm getting KeyError: 'st_trendup'.
Can you help with that ?

Comment: @Charizard_knows_to_code - What column should be shifted?

Comment: st_trendup. That part is correct. But still I am still getting key error.

Comment: @Charizard_knows_to_code - But problem is `st_trendup` not exist before, so cannot shift.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this type of recursion ? Or maybe setting a few values of top as NaN ?

Comment: @Charizard_knows_to_code - ya, try `df['st_trendup'] = np.nan`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240302/discussion-between-charizard-knows-to-code-and-jezrael).